# C dynamic allocation with realloc of a char**

Tags: c, memory, char, allocation, realloc

I'm new here and don't speak very well english.
I've a question concerning my code (in C).

What the code should do:
There exists a file named "g.txt", that should be opened. Then it reads it line by line and copies each line in a buffer (`zpuffer[200]`), after that the content of the buffer should be copied with strcpy to `**Dfile`. `**Dfile` points to a `char*`, its space was first allocated with `malloc`. If `**Dfile` hasn't enough space for saving, the code executes `realloc`, that shoud make more free space.

The first time `realloc` have been called, I actually got more space! But the second time, it didn't work; the OS, Ubuntu, says (in German): "Bus-Zugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)". English: "Bus access error (written dump)"

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OBJS 10 //new Lines a one time for **Dfile

int main(void){
FILE *datei;
datei=fopen("g.txt", "r");
if (datei == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "\nFEHLER\n");
    return 1;
}

char zpuffer[200]; //buffer
char **Dfile; //save content of g.txt line by line, every line has its own index

int zeilen = 0; //the actual amount of lines
int speicher = 0; //total indices in **Dfile    
Dfile = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**)*(speicher + OBJS));
speicher += OBJS;   

while (fgets(zpuffer, 199, datei) != NULL){ 
    if (speicher <= zeilen){//speicher <= zeilen --> allocate memory
        Dfile = (char**)realloc(*Dfile, sizeof(char**)*(speicher + OBJS)); //!!ERROR!! but just the second time!!
        if (Dfile == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "\nFEHLER Alloc\n");
            return 1;
        }           
        speicher += OBJS;
    }

    Dfile[zeilen]=malloc(strlen(zpuffer)+1);
    strcpy(Dfile[zeilen++], zpuffer);       
    printf("%s", Dfile[zeilen - 1]);    
}
return 0;
}
```

May someone help me, please??

Comment: `Dfile = realloc(Dfile, sizeof *Dfile * (speicher+OBJS));` (and `Dfile = malloc(sizeof(*Dfile *(speicher + OBJS));` ) OR: `Dfile = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (speicher + OBJS));` if you want, but that is more error-prone ... Plus: you don't need the initial malloc(); `ptr = realloc(NULL, new_size);` works as expected.

Comment: first - test the result of mallic. second run the program under a debugger, you dont say what platform so I cant say what debugger you need

Comment: Additional `fgets(zpuffer, 199, datei)` -> `fgets(zpuffer, 200, datei)` .

Comment: I use ubuntu. Actually I tested the code, the error comes from the realloc

Comment: Even if your english is bad, try to write all comments and especially **variable identifiers** in english. The next best thing would be to do it consistently in german. Just an advise ;)

Comment: @joop small change `Dfile = malloc(sizeof *Dfile *(speicher + OBJS));`  { () do not balance in your comment }

Comment: @Fragender99 `fgets` will terminate it with `'\0'` so no need to leave additional space for it . It will write `199` characters  and add a `'\0'` at end .

Comment: Aha, I needed to snip yet another '(' :  Too late for edit, now!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked... :-)

Comment: Please also indent your code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `*Dfile` to `realloc()`.

Did you meant to pass `Dfile` instead?

Comment: ***Dfile is a pointer to char*. So I wish to "add" more char*-Pointers to it.

Comment: Dfile is a pointer to pointers which point to strings, right? You've got too many strings, so you need to add more pointers, not more chars. -- Instead what you do is re-allocating the first line and then assigning the resulting pointer to Dfile, which, most likely will cause some sort of crash down the line.